# Syntax command to change specific value in column

Tags: syntax, spss, recode

I did a little research and gave my respondents the option "other" where they could specify where they're from if not from those categories that I gave them as options. This "other" category has been coded as category "6". But some people didn't read  the existing categories well and wrote essentially what was given to them as an option. How can I change this in the dataset? So change a specific value "6" to "2" while using SPSS syntax? I tried looking everywhere but I haven't been able to find an answer :(

Comment: `if` command will probably do it. eg. `if OpenAnswer="some existing category" category=2.` or `if var1>4 and var2=6 and category=6 category=2.`

Answer (score 0):

if your variable is var1; you can write and run in a syntax window:

```
recode var1 (6=2).
execute.
```

This will replace all 6 in var1 with a 2.

You can also create a new var2, hence making sure you are not overwriting your original var1:

```
recode var1 (6=2) (else=copy) into var2.
execute.
```

You might want to do this only for respondents you have identified as not having read all the answers correctly. Then you might want to create an additional variable:

```
misread
```

with values 1 if you want to change 6 into 2, and 0 if you want to keep 6.

Your code is, then:

```
do if  (misread = 1).
recode var1 (6=2) (else=copy) into var2.
end if.
```